# Digi 865LP xbee modules in point to multipoint network

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, xbee, zigbee

I am very new to xbee networks.
Earlier i had used Xbee modules by simply sending data using UART interface of controller unit.As per my information , a Xbee is basically a trans-receiver, which can send data and also can receive.But for that they need to work in same frequency range( a pretty easy to understand fact).

Recently i came to know about a new series of Xbee modules , which Digi has launched keeping in mind scenarios existing in India.
[Digi Xbee Module 865LP](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90002126_A.pdf) are the one which working in 863 MHz and 870 MHz range.Recently i came to know that these modules cannot communicate among each other.I didn't find any reason behind that.I want to use 865LP in a point to multi-point network.

Also if the above point that 2 865LP modules cannot communicate among each other then what RX(receiver module) can i use , so that  that module act as RX for all the 865LP working as TX.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a inquiry at Digi support forum and i got this reply.

"The Xbee 868 LP can only communicate with another Xbee 868 LP. It can’t talk to the European version at 868 MHz. I suspect that this is what your reseller was talking about.
Yes this device can support Point to Point and Point to Multipoint as well as Mesh. It is as very good choice for deployment in India."